# How to create a new Mongoose document, and then update before saving

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to create a new Mongoose document first

```
let newTrade = new TradeModel({
  userId: userId,
  symbol: symbol
})
```

Then I need to send this item to another server, to get the other details

```
    let orderReceived = await sendOrderToServer(newTrade);
```

And then I want to merger this in with the new document and save

```
    newTrade = {...newTrade, ...orderReceived}
```

But once I alter the original document, I loose access to the `.save()` method.  I cant run `.save()` first becasue its missing required fields.  I really just need the `Trade._id` first before sending to the other server which is why I'm doing it this way.  Any suggestions? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `mongoose.Types.ObjectId()` constructor to create an id and then send that to your server, when the response comes back, create a document based on that.

EDIT: Adding few examples for clarity

```js
let newTradeId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(); // With "new" or without, Javascript lets you use object constructors without instantiating

let orderReceived = await sendOrderToServer(newTradeId);

let newTrade = new TradeModel({ ...orderReceived }); // Create the newTrade by destructuring the order received.

// TADA! We are done!
```